# order_by based on condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a queryset of assignment modules. i want to order the query set based on custom conditions.

My view:

```
class ListAssignmentsAsStudent(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = AssignmentModuleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        my_enrolments = UserEnrolment.objects.filter(
            user=self.request.user).values_list('enrolment')
        my_enrolment_enrollables = Enrollable.objects.filter(
            enrolment__in=my_enrolments)
        assignment_modules = []
        for enrollable in my_enrolment_enrollables:
            assignment_modules.extend(enrollable.course_share_item.modules.instance_of(
                AssignmentModule))
        return assignment_modules
```

All "UserEnrolment"s have a completion_status. "AssignmentModule"s have a due date DateTimeField field .I want to order the Queryset in this order. Assignments not submitted and due date already passed will be in overdue and these should come first. Assignments not submitted should come in order of due dates , earliest should come first. Assignments with UserEnrolment completion_status as COMPLETED should come with least priority .These will be the last in the list. After the ordering assignments will be in this order.

```
Overdue>not submitted with due dates earliest first> submitted assignments
```

AssignmentModule's progress is maintained in model:

```
class ModuleProgress(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        ElsUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    module = models.ForeignKey(
        Module, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False, blank=False)
    completion_status = models.IntegerField(
        default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    progress_percentage = models.IntegerField(
        default=0, null=False, blank=True)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(ModuleProgressNote)
```

module is the assignment and when the completion status is 2, the assignment is submitted, completion status None is assignment not submitted

Comment: When is an assignment not submitted? If it does not exists, you can not order it in any way . Is it possible to share relevant parts of the models you work with?

Comment: ok  @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem any answer?